# Custom form values without plugin

Tags: forms

I just started working on wordpress.

Now i have created custom form and that form data I want to save in database and mail also.

For that form creation, I have one php file which i have used as template on one page.

and then that form submit, i have given action to another page [ which also made by custom template].

I am having problem, like on form submit, the action page is opening but i am not able to get data.

form is like same..

```
<form action="/submit-idea" method="post" name="idea">
<label>Idea Outline<div class='info'>Brief description of the product or service idea</div></label>
<textarea id="idea-outline" cols="10" rows="3" placeholder="" required></textarea>
```

and on submit-idea page,
I am trying to get values like,

```
$idea_outline = $_POST['idea-outline'];
```

But their is no values, in that variable ?

and BTW, that submit-idea is php page which i have used as template on page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly a WordPress question, because you made an error in your form.

Try adding name="idea-outline" to your textarea, and you should be fine.